# When rolling Mr Monopoly do I move to Auction to a property

Tags: monopoly-mega-edition

If I roll Mr. Monopoly on the speed die, and all the properties have been bought, according to the rules I have to move to the next place that I have to pay rent. I am not clear what is the rule if the next place is the **Auction** which according to the rules makes me move to the place with the highest rent. Do I have to move to Auction or do I move to the next **property** which has cheaper rent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latter (you move to the next property which has cheaper rent.). It's not the next "place" in the rule, it's the next **property** .

From [The Rules](https://www.winning-moves.com/images/megamonopolyrules.pdf)

> If you roll a Mr. Monopoly after all of the properties are
>   owned, make a normal move according to the white
>   dice, then move ahead to the first **property** on which you
>   need to pay rent

(emphasis added)